# Tomcat Seems to send only 64k to a socket, then waits for ack before sending next 64k chunk of data

Tags: performance, sockets, tomcat, tcp, send

We observe the following behavior with tomcat when transferring large files. The server sends 64k of tcp data with max segment size (mss=1469, so 44*1460 bytes, plus 1*1296 bytes) without any delays. So there is no issue with Nagle on the server side. When the last packet is sent, it has the Push flag set, which indicates to me that the send buffer is emptied.

Then there is an unwanted delay of 200ms before receiving the final ACK from client. obviously this is because the client uses tcp delayed ack (a behavior I can't influence) and we have an unequal number of segments.

From my understanding, in case tomcat would continously send data, we would avoid this 200ms delay after each 64k of tcp data.

Questions:

1. Is it expected behavior for tomcat to send just 64k, then wait for the final ack before sending more data?
2. Is there any means to tune the tomcat behavior to have it sending data more continously (without draining the sendbuffer after each 64k chunk of data)?

Comment: This video https://packetbomb.com/solving-tomcat-throughput-issues-on-windows/ talks about this problem, it seems changing a buffer size solved it more or less. But no real reason given...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it expected behavior for tomcat to send just 64k, then wait for the final ack before sending more data?

No. Neither Tomcat nor any other Java application can 'wait for a final ACK'. You don't see them at all. Tomcat just writes to a socket output stream.

> Is there any means to tune the tomcat behavior to have it sending data more continously (without draining the sendbuffer after each 64k chunk of data)?

It isn't Tomcat behaviour in the first place. The behaviour is almost certainly due to TCP.

Comment: Ok, let me be more precise. It is clear ro me, that only the TCP stack sees the ACKs. Nevertheless, Tomcat seems to wait for a "signal" from the stack somehow. This is unexpexted to me - as you stated I would expect the application (tomcat) just to write to the socket output stream.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is, that tomcat is writing 64k of data to the socket, but then waits for too long before continuing to send the next 64k of data.

Comment: As I found not much doc about the output behavior of sockets - how would be the expected behavior here? As I stated, the server is sending the last packet of the 64k chunk with push bit set which indicates to me the the send buffer runs empty. So from TCP stack view, there should be nothing which prevents tomcat to send more data?

Comment: A kind of workaround to the issue we face would be to adjust the MSS in a way that each 64k chunk of data is sent in a even number of packets.

Comment: Currently: MSS=1460, so 44x1460 + 1296 = 45 packets

Comment: Workaround: MSS=1456, so 45x1456 + 16 =46 packets

Comment: But isn't there a way to tweak the behavior how Tomcat fills the socket buffer to avoid this 64k blocks?